# Can I tell Nancy to only search in the current assembly for modules?

Tags: .net, nancy

I have over a hundred .dlls in my application directory, I dont want Nancy to search through all of them to find a single module on startup.

Can I tell Nancy to only search in the current assembly?

Comment: Really? Wtf... That's insane... Maybe you should restructure your app.

Comment: not possible, it should be a fairly common scenario to have lots of dlls in your app directory

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `AppDomainAssemblyTypeScanner.AssembliesToScan` to specify which assemblies Nancy should scan.

By default it will scan `Nancy.dll` and all other assemblies with a reference to `Nancy.dll`, except the ones with a name starting with `Nancy.Testing`.

This means that even though you have hundreds of assemblies in your `AppDomain`, Nancy won't scan all of them.